# Is there someone that could help me with Contact-form validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, bootstrap-4, submit, contact-form

I am trying to combine inputs validation functions with submit function in order to have fully functional simple contact-form that reacts to wrong/right input types and empty fields. Using boostrap 4, read documentation of validation but I don't understand why contact form is sent even if only one field is filled and it does not require email :/ :(. I'm noob at JS, not able to do that and going crazy -stacked there for 8 hours. Commented code in the script.js is there coz i tried to combine different things.

Is there someone, that could rewrite me the functions ?

Here is the code for form:

```js
'use strict';
//---------Contact form SEND-----------
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');  
  // get the form elements defined in your form HTML above
  var form = document.getElementById("bootstrapForm");
  // var button = document.getElementById("my-form-button");
  var status = document.getElementById("status");

  // Success and Error fn-s after form submission
  function success() {
    form.reset();
    status.classList.add("success");
    status.innerHTML = "Správa bola úspešne odoslaná.";
  }

  function error() {
    status.classList.add("error");
    status.innerHTML = "Pri odosielaní správy sa vyskytol problém";
  }



  var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
    // handle the form submission event
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var data = new FormData(form);
        ajax(form.method, form.action, data, success, error);
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated');
    }, false);
  });
}, false);

// helper function for sending an AJAX request

function ajax(method, url, data, success, error) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) return;
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      success(xhr.response, xhr.responseType);
    } else {
      error(xhr.status, xhr.response, xhr.responseType);
    }
  };
  xhr.send(data);
}









$(function()
{



    // Contact forms
    "use strict";

    // Detect when form-control inputs are not empty
    $(".cool-b4-form .form-control").on("input", function() {
      if ($(this).val()) {
        $(this).addClass("hasValue");
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("hasValue");
      }
    });


});
```

Here is my website (form is at bottom) so that you can see it on the move: https://marekcmarko.sk

Answer (score 0):

I am noob here too and do not know how to write the functions you require.
However, by reading the problem I suppose you could solve it by adding the "required" attribute directly to your html. That way, if a field in your form is not filled, the form will not be sent. Also the type attribute can help with the validation of the right type of input.

```html
<form>
        <div>
        <label for="Name">First Name:</label>
        <input id="Name" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="John" required>

        <label for="Last Name">Last Name:</label>
        <input id="Last Name" type="text" name="Last Name" placeholder="Smith" required>
        </div>

        <div>
        <label>
        Male
        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male">
        </label>

        <label>
        Female
        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female">
        </label>

        <label>
        Other
        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Other">
        </label>
        </div>

        <div>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required>

        <label>
            Password:
            <input type="password" name="password" pattern=".{5,10}" required title="Enter  5 to 10 characters">
        </label>
        </div>


        <div>
        

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Birthday:</legend>
            <label for="month">Month:</label>
            <select name="month" id="month">
                <option value="january">Jan</option>
                <option value="february">Feb</option>
                <option value="march">Mar</option>
                <option value="april">Apr</option>
            </select>

            <label for="day">Day</label>
            <select name="day" id="day">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
            <label for="year">Year</label>
            <select name="year" id="year">
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>

        </div>
        
        <div>
        <label for="Terms">I agree to the terms and conditions</label>
        <input id="Terms" type="checkbox" name="Terms" value="x">
        </div>

        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```